# Grunt creating file with random number in the file name?

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman, minify, uglifyjs

I have used yeoman to create an angular project. When I build, the app.js file is created in the dist folder but the file name is app.js, but it is app.2bf032ifs.js
I don't know why?

Below is how I have written my uglify -

```
uglify: {
     build: {
         src: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/**/*.js',
         dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/app.js'
}
},
```

While running the Grunt command I get the message

```
Running "ngtemplates:dist" (ngtemplates) task
File .tmp/templateCache.js created.
>> Usemin has not created uglify.generated yet!
```

1) I do not know how to get the correct filename in the dist folder, how?
2) How to get rid of the above message?
3) Filename, similar behavior while generating the final css file also.

Note - Below is my usemin task

```
usemin: {
  html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
  css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
  js: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'],
  options: {
    assetsDirs: [
      '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
      '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images',
      '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles'
    ],
    patterns: {
      js: [[/(images\/[^''""]*\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|webp|svg))/g, 'Replacing references to images']]
    }
  }
},
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because of a task named 'filerev', this strategy is used to tell the browser to download a new copy of the file everytime so that its not cached. If you do not want it to happen then comment the task 'filerev'.

Something like :

```
grunt.registerTask('build', [
'clean:dist',
'wiredep',
'useminPrepare',
'concurrent:dist',
'postcss',
'ngtemplates',
'concat',
'ngAnnotate',
'copy:dist',
'cdnify',
'cssmin',
'uglify',
//'filerev',
'usemin',
'htmlmin'
```

]);